# How to record bagfile within launch file

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to record some topics via launch file.

```
<!-- record topics -->
<node name="record_topics_for_verification" pkg="rosbag" type="record"
      args="$(arg topics_name)"/>
```

This code runs without any errors, however, there is no recorded bagfile in current directory.

Does anyone know the reason?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251535/how-to-record-bagfile-within-launch-file/) by [baozhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/25430/baozhang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2017-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By default, the bag file will be in `~/.ros` folder with the name being the date and time of starting recording. For exact name, you can add this flag `output="screen"` so it looks like this

`<node name="record_topics_for_verification" pkg="rosbag" type="record" args="$(arg topics_name)" output="screen"/>`

After adding this flag, you will see the bag name in rosout after you launch.

Note: the bag file will have the name of `xxx.bag.active` while being recording. Only after you properly terminate the recording node, the file name will be changed to `xxx.bag`

---

Originally posted by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) with karma: 544 on 2017-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [baozhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/25430/baozhang/) on 2017-01-09**:
Thank you for replying.

I found recorded bagfiles in ~/.ros folder.

Do you know how to change the folder to record bagfiles?

**Comment by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) on 2017-01-09**:
You can add `-o` in args list. Follow this: http://answers.ros.org/question/106126/giving-a-directory-to-output-file-in-a-launcher-for-rosbag-record-and-rostopic-echo/?answer=222874#post-id-222874

**Comment by [baozhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/25430/baozhang/) on 2017-01-10**:
Thank you for your kindness.
My question was solved!